# using Dropzone.js and php to show the contents of uploaded file to a textfield without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js to implement file upload. I am using it to make a web compiler. Using php/ajax I want to show the contents of the file in the editor text area without saving the file in the server.

My current code snippets are-
    `<form role="form">
    <textarea id="editor">
    <?php if( isset( $data['source'] ) ) 
    echo $data['source']; ?></textarea>
    </form>`

```
`    <form class="dropzone dz-clickable" action="upload.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload element"></i>
<div style="color:gray;">Drag and drop or click to upload file</div>
<input type="hidden" name="filenameEmail" class="filenameEmail" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="side" value="front">
</form>`
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @BobbyW  what i have is a complex code and without comments. it is very hard to understand. if anyone can give me some idea for above query? i can implement it by my own. And please do not downflag my question, i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: @YashGoel if you don't provide at least a bit of code it's very unlikely someone is able to help you properly. You should trust people on this platform to understand you're code. As there are always hundreds of ways to solve a problem it is IMHO required to see what you did so far to not force you to change your code completely only because someone is taking another road you would.

Comment: @Mr.Moe i have edited the question!

Answer (score 0):

with the bit of code provided it's a bit hard to get to a proper solution fitting your needs.

generally (and as you asked for only an idea of how you could do it) however, I'd go with using the *success* event from dropzone.js which provides the server response as the second parameter according to there [Documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-success).

So what you do is reading out the data from the uploaded file using your **upload.php** and returning it so you can use it in the told event.

Easiest way (as always) is using jQuery with it to have full control of the response and assign the provided text/code/whatever to the

`$('#editor').val();`